# Coinbase - get_spot_price - historical

Tags: python, coinbase-api

Must be a newbie question.
Trying to fetch the historical daily spot prices on coinbase.
Using the python implementation of the api as follows.

https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-spot-price

```
price = client.get_spot_price(currency_pair= 'BTC-USD', date='2016-5-10')
```

Result (actually today's price):

```
    2016-5-10
{
  "amount": "5613.84",
  "base": "BTC",
  "currency": "USD"
}
```

I get the current spot price. Could anyone shade some light on what I am missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you simply hit the URI yourself, it works fine:

https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot?date=2017-05-10

That gives a reasonable answer (plus a warning which we can ignore for the purpose of this question):

```
{"data":{"base":"BTC","currency":"USD","amount":"1758.04"},"warnings":[{"id":"missing_version","message":"Please supply API version (YYYY-MM-DD) as CB-VERSION header","url":"https://developers.coinbase.com/api#versioning"}]}
```

So somewhere along the way you are making the wrong query.  Either the library is broken, or you are using it in a way other than what you have said you are doing.  Try the above URL, and then try using a tool like Wireshark to see what your library-based solution is querying.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the API could not get the parameters to a json request.
It's throwing the parameters dict in a 'clean_params' function which always returns an empty dictionary.

In the API file util.py line 31

```
def encode_params(params, **kwargs):
  """Clean and JSON-encode a dict of parameters."""
  cleaned = clean_params(params, **kwargs)
  return json.dumps(params) # changed from cleaned (was empty) to params
```

I know it's not clean but it works.

```
price = client.get_spot_price(currency_pair = 'BTC-USD',date='2014-05-10')

{
  "amount": "453.19", 
  "base": "BTC", 
  "currency": "USD"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @farbiondriven although i don't see any change

Answer (score 0):

From the API:

> Specify date for historic spot price in format YYYY-MM-DD (UTC)

Might be that you need to specify 2 digits for the month

```
price = client.get_spot_price(currency_pair= 'BTC-USD', date='2016-05-10')
```

Comment: Well spotted on the syntax but unfortunately no effect.

Comment: Then in that case, it seems like a bug in the API, so I would suggest opening an issue against the Python API you are using.